# Change function based on input value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve is that #alert should be able to be made visible when input value is 0 or doesn't exist. When input value is other than 0 it should remain hidden even if another option is being selected.

it should work like that:

1) select an option

2) alert appears

3) fill input (other than 0)

4) alert dissapears

5) it won't appear unless input value is changed to 0 or removed, even if you change option again

```js
jQuery('#mydiv').after('<span id="alert">alert</span>');
  jQuery('select').change(function() {
jQuery('#alert').toggle(this.value !== '');
});
```

```css
#alert {
  display: block;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
jQuery('#mydiv').after('<span id="alert">alert</span>');

jQuery('select').change(function() {
  var input_val = jQuery('#some_input').val();
  var show_alert = (input_val == 0 || input_val == "");

  show_hide_alert(show_alert);
});

jQuery('#some_input').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var show_alert = ( val == 0 || val == "" );

  show_hide_alert(show_alert);
});

function show_hide_alert(show) {
  if( show ) {
    jQuery('#alert').show();
  } else {
    jQuery('#alert').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#alert {
  display: block;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input id="some_input" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#mydiv').after('<span id="alert">alert</span>');
jQuery('select').change(function() {
    if(this.value == 0 || this.value == ''){
        jQuery('#alert').toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't hide the alert if value is positive.

Comment: Please comment your solutions - this will show and hide whenever an empty or 0 value is selected

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

1. Initially, `alert` will be hidden.
2. When any option is selected,
   `alert` is displayed.
3. When any text is entered, other than 0 and
   blank then the `alert` is hidden even when the select option is
   changed.
4. When the input value is 0 or blank then the `alert` is
   displayed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#mydiv').after('<span id="alert" style="display:none;">alert</span>');

    jQuery('select').change(function () {
        var inputVal = $.trim($('input').val());
        jQuery('#alert').toggle(this.text !== '' && (inputVal === "" || inputVal == "0"));
    });

    jQuery('input').focusout(function(){
        var inputVal = $.trim($(this).val());
        jQuery('#alert').toggle((inputVal === "" || inputVal == "0"));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<input value="">
```

Answer (score -1):

So you have 2 events:

- select change event: alert should appear
- input change event: alert should appear/disappear whether input is empty/0 or not

Here's my solution:

```js
jQuery('#myDiv').after('<span id="alert">alert</span>');
jQuery('#mySelect').change(function() { jQuery('#alert').toggle(true); });
jQuery('#myInput').change(function() {
  jQuery('#alert').toggle(this.value == 0 || this.value == '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <input id="myInput" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: This does nothing

Comment: Yes, I accidentally made a 1 character typo (as I tried to follow OPs continuous edits). Really worth a downvote, thanks...